# How many series in length $n$ above $\{3, 5, 7\}$ there are with "$35$" in?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many series in length $n$ above $\{3, 5, 7\}$ there are with "$35$" in?

I though that we should find a place for "$35$", so there are $n-1$ of these. And then we place "35" there and we just have to decide of the rest of the $n-2$ digits, so in the end we have $(n-1)3^{n-2}$. But apparently I'm counting series more then once...

Comment: Of course, for example you are counting the sequence $(3, 5, 3, 5)$ twice.

Comment: If $n=4$, you count $3535$ twice. Once for $35$ in the first position, and once for $35$ in the last position.

Comment: I mentioned it, I know my solution is wrong and I'm asking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the answer involves the Fibonacci numbers.
Specifically:

Let $T_n$ be the number of strings of length $n$ that have no instance of $35$ (you can then get your desired answer by subtracting from the total number of sequences). Call such strings "good".

It helps to refine this number slightly:  Let $A_n$ be the number of good sequences that start with $3$, $B_n$ are the number that start with $5$, and $C_n$ the number the start with $7$.  We note that $T_n=A_n+B_n+C_n$ and $A_1=B_1=C_1=3$

We easily get the recursions:  $$A_n=A_{n-1}+C_{n-1}$$ $$B_n=A_{n-1}+B_{n-1} +C_{n-1}$$ $$C_n=A_{n-1}+B_{n-1} +C_{n-1}$$  Whence we conclude that $B_n=C_n$ and we can eliminate $C_n$  to get $$A_n=A_{n-1}+B_{n-1}$$ $$B_n=A_{n-1}+2B_{n-1}$$ $$T_n=A_{n}+2B_{n}$$

This system is easily solved, especially if you compute the first few terms and notice that the $A's$ and $B's$ alternate to give you the Fibonacci numbers.  In particular $T_n=F_{2n+1}$

The answer you want is the total number of strings of length $n$ less $T_n$ hence $3^n-F_{2n+1}$